# using Regex to replace a printf("", x, y); to ... in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: regex

Replace `printf(" some string %s %d", str, nVal);`

To

`SHOWMSG(ZONE, (TEXT(" some string %s %d"), str, nVal));`

So I try use Find/Replace with regular expression options to replace

I had created `(printf[ \t]*\([ \t]*)((\".+?\")|('.+?'))([ \t]*)(,?.*)\);` to search, but when trying to replace I got some trouble?

any help ...

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
.*?\" (.*?) %s %d\", (.*?), (.*?)\)
```

with

```
SHOWMSG(ZONE, (TEXT("$1 %s %d"), $2, $3));
```